# Android GridLayoutManager one background image for whole row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I am trying to make simple layout but can't get it work. Goal is to have activity which show (configurable) count of books like books on shelf.

I have recycler view in main activity (so I can scroll all of them) with grid layout manager (so I can configure number of books in row).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bookshelfRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

My problem is, that I have to set up background image for each row, but the image is used for each book. Like when I want 3 books in row I have 3 bcgr images instead of one wrapping whole row.

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/shelfcell_background">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="103dp"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I set background image for whole row (now matter how many books there are)?

[bookshelf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OpXg.png) - I have "new" background (brown) under each image but I need this one background cover whole row

Comment: can you post some screenshot?

Comment: screen viz bookshelf

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround where you have to cut your background (brown) shelf image into 3 equal parts.

The first item on your data will have the 1st part of the image and the last item of the row have the last part of the image. and the 2nd item has the middle part.

This way you can set the shelf background to the whole row and not just one/book.

I hope you get what I want to say. First, cut the background image with some editor or something or paint.

Suppose you have 5 items in a row.

**item 1** - part1 of the image.
**item 2** - part2 of the image.
**item 3** - part2 of the image.
**item 4** - part2 of the image.
**item 5** - part3 of the image.

Comment: Thank you Aman :) you´re right this would solve the problem. But on the other hand it looks like too much. Isn´t there any other way maybe even with combining other view / layout ? I am thinking about linear layout for which I set background and dynamically set number of images... but I am beginner so not sure if this might work. I´ll give it a try.

Comment: There are other ways too but they are a lot more complicated than this. This is the easiest way IMHO or maybe the only way. You can do one thing, add a vertical recyclerview and your grid layout manager above it. You need to take RelativeLayout as the parent view. And set the transparency of the gridlayout item to 100%. But for this you need to make a separate data class to know the exact number of recyclerview item which is, in your case, totalnumberofgriditem/3, your recyclerview items. I hope you get it.